# Import a package beyond top-level package using importlib

Tags: python, python-importlib

I am looking to import a package (plugin) outside my current directory.  Say I have a directory structure:

```
/plugins
   /test2
      __init__.py
      test_file.py
/src
   main.py
```

The `main.py` has the following:

```
import importlib
import pkgutil
import os
import sys

module_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/../plugins")

for finder, name, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules([module_dir]):
    print(finder, name, ispkg)
    test = importlib.import_module(name, package='..plugins')
    print(test.test_file.test_variable)
```

The `test_file.py` has the following:

```
test_variable = "testing"
```

With this current code, I would get an error of:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test2'
```

When I try to add `sys.path.append(module_dir)` so the path is included, I would get an error:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

What would be the best way to implement this and import the package/plugin?  Assuming I could have multiple package under the plugin folder

Comment: When I run your code (after setting everything up) no errors occur. It just prints out something like `FileFinder('C:\\Stack Overflow\\import_test\\src/../plugins') test True` and ends normally. I'm using Python 3.8.0 on Windows.

Comment: Thats weird, though I am using python 3.7.3 on windows.  I will try 3.8 but I have problem installing numpy with python 3.8. <update> Tried with python 3.8 and still having the same issues...

Comment: I doubt it's because you're using 3.7. Is there anything further I can do to verify whether it's really working or not (beyond just not getting an error)?

Comment: I updated the question.  Try to add the test_variable under test_file and see if you can access it in main.py after importing the module.  Also when you said it works, did it work with the original code or when you add sys.path.append?

Comment: After doing that there is an error: `AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute 'test_file'`. If I put a `print('test:', test)` right before the `print(test.test_file.test_variable)` it displays `test: <module 'test' (namespace)>` right before that.

Comment: Ok, I am now getting exactly what you are getting. Two questions.  With your setup, howcome testfile.test_variable cannot be accessed? Second question, if you update the folder 'test' to 'test2', then you will get the initial error i was getting that no named module 'test2', you know why that is?

Comment: Well, when I rename the folder name to `test2` I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test2'`. I don't know why the `test.test_file.test_variable` cannot be accessed (before making the change).

Comment: Yea so the 'test2' example was the initial question/error I was having.  I guess I renamed it to 'test' just to simplify the real name of the folder, but turns out that works and gets imported.  But even with that it cannot be accessed...